# How do I make this macro run on the sheet which is open?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The macro deletes columns I don't need, by deleting all of them except the ones with names specified.

I can't work out (and it should be easy) how to just make it work on any worksheet, not one with a particular name. The macro is stored in personal.xlsb. How do I do that?

```
Sub DeleteUnnecessaryColumns()

Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim startCell As Range
Dim colnames
Dim here As Boolean

colnames = Array("first column I want to keep", "Second column I want to keep", "goes on for ages")

Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("export")
Set startCell = currentSht.Range("A1")

lastRow = startCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lastCol = startCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

With currentSht
    For i = lastCol To 1 Step -1
        here = False
        For j = LBound(colnames) To UBound(colnames)
            If .Cells(1, i).Value = colnames(j) Then
                here = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not here Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the macro to run on the sheet that is active, replace:

```
Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("export")
```

with:

```
Set currentSht = ActiveSheet
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something simple but couldn't quite figure it.

Comment: @NeMo  You are quite welcome.  If we don't ask questions, we won't get answers.